# Enabled CORS but has no effect

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have followed this article...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I have added `services.AddCors();` in `ConfigureServices` and `app.UseCors(b => b.AllowAnyOrigin());` in `Configure`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I still get...

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

What else must I do?

Comment: Make sure `UseCors` is before other middleware that returns a response and also check that the server is not throwing any exceptions (CORS headers don’t get set if in that case).

Comment: @KirkLarkin You rock. I changed the order in `Configure`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by KirkLarkin in the comments section, app.UseCors() should be called before any other middleware which returns a response. It wouldn't hurt to put it as the first line in your Configure method.